# Autodesk Forge web application - from visual studio code to close .exe file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, exe, autodesk-forge

I have a working forge application ( bim360 hub sidebar with forge viewer  and some charts).

It is currently running from Visual Studio Code IDE only. I want to build the app into an .exe file in order to be able to send it to a user, upload it to a server with IIS, etc..

General details:

- I used Petr Broz tutorial to set up the backend of the viewer and hub
  (Forge online training - view your models https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-O1e3gXCOEQ&t=8986s )
- The app is running on Node.js

I tried to use 'nexe' module and build executable file. With this method, I need to specify `index.js` file ("an entry point") and define a 'nexe.config.js' file. I used the entry point `start.js`.
Eventually, I managed to create an exe file - and when I run it from the command line, I get an error

> Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.

although I have them in the `config.js`

Main questions:

- Is there another way to build a close exe file from visual studio code - for a forge web application?
- Am i doing something wrong with the processes I mention above?
- Is it even possible to deploy a web application to IIS using an exe file?? all of the documentation points toward Azur, AWS and heroku..

Relevant files:

**1)** `start.js`:

```
const path = require('path');//bringing in built in node js modeules ( to resulve file system path )
const express = require('express');//module to create the express server 
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session'); 
//any piece of code would have an opportunity to handle the request 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const config = require('./config.js');
if (config.credentials.client_id == null || config.credentials.client_secret == null) {
    console.error('Missing FORGE_CLIENT_ID or FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET env. variables.');
    return;
}

let app = express();
//static middlewere to check for the front end files (html,js,css)
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));//method inside express module: a middlewere for serving static files  this line will check in 'public' folder if the request 
//that is sent (specific file) is in there. if so - it will ignore the rest of the stack(the rest of the code)
app.use(cookieSession({
    // create 2 cookies that stores the name and encripted key 
    name: 'forge_session',
    keys: ['forge_secure_key'],//takes cater of decipher the encription for the forge key for us 
    maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 14 days, same as refresh token
}));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));//middlewere that looks at the title of the request - and if its .json it will look at the body of the request and parese it to javascript object
app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/oauth.js'));//adding our custom express routers that will handle the different endpoints.
app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/datamanagement.js'));
app.use('/api/forge', require('./routes/user.js'));
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
});
app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`); });
```

**2)** `config.js`:

```
// Autodesk Forge configuration
module.exports = {
    // Set environment variables or hard-code here
    credentials: {
        client_id: process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: process.env.FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callback_url: process.env.FORGE_CALLBACK_URL
    },
    scopes: {
        // Required scopes for the server-side application-->privliges for our internal opperation in the server side ("back end")
        internal: ['bucket:create', 'bucket:read', 'data:read', 'data:create', 'data:write'],
        // Required scope for the client-side viewer-->priveliges for the client ("front end") 
        public: ['viewables:read']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Author of the tutorial here :)

I'm not sure how `nexe` works exactly but please note that the sample app expects input parameters such as `FORGE_CLIENT_ID` or `FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET` to be provided as **environment variables**.

As a first step, try running your *.exe file after setting the env. variables in your command prompt.

If that doesn't work, try hard-coding the input parameters directly into the `config.js` file (replacing any of the `process.env.*` references), and then bundle everything into an *.exe file. This is just for debugging purposes, though! You shouldn't share your credentials with anyone, not even inside an *.exe file. So as an alternative I'd suggest that you update the sample app to read the input parameters from somewhere else, perhaps from a local file.

Comment: Hey Peter! Thank you for your comment (and amazing  work making the tutorials). When you say "update te app to read the input parameters from a local file" you mean a file in the  main folder of the app? Or there is another local file that I can "pull"  the credentials from without including them in the  bundle ?( If there is some documentation that you could reference me to, It would be great!) Thanks again(:

Comment: I'm no expert on `nexe` so again, you may need to consult their documentation :) What I'm suggesting is: if your *.exe file cannot see environment variables, you could just provide your client ID and secret in some simple JSON file sitting next to your *.exe file, and have your *.exe file read it.

Comment: You could then distribute the *.exe file to other people, and they would have to provide their own JSON file with the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

after trying a lot of solutions, i got to the conclusion that the reason that nothing happened was that the oathantication files ( with the clint_id and clint_password) was not embedded in the .exe file.
the way to include those files with the nexe module is to use the flag -r "Foldername/subfoldername/filename.js".

first, crate a nexe.config.js file that would contain the entry point file name to the app. ( in my case, the file name is " start.js")
second, write the following commands in the command line:

```
cd C:\Projects\MyAppFolder 

npm install -g nexe
// specify all the files you want to include inside the exe file
 nexe start.js -r "config.js" -r "nexe.config.js" -r "routes/common/oauth.js" -r "routes/*.js" -r "public//." -r ".vscode/**/." -r "package-lock.json" -r "package.json" --build --output "AppName.exe"
```